# How can I get the entitytype (Phone call, fax, ...) from the returned activitypointer value?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ribbon

This issue relates to crm 2011. I created a command in the ribbon that calls a javascript function passing the crmParameter SelectedEntityTypeName. Everything works as expected until I trigger it with a selected Activity from the Activities page. It returns me ActivityPointer as EntityTypeName.

Is there a way to receive the ActivityTypeName (Phone Call, Fax, ...) and not the generic ActivityPointer as SelectedEntityType, when triggering the command from the Activities page?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We want to help you, but please read ['What topics can I ask about'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ['How to Ask'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question so we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks Danny H. I changed the subject and tried to narrow the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Instead of retrieving the *SelectedEntityType*, that will return the type *ActivityPointer*, I added as return value the *crmParameter* *SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences* and accessed to the desired information via *returnedValue[i].TypeName*